# How to combine database-stored and app-hardcoded instances of the same class in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have an app which has several classes, let's call them `School` and `Subject`. I have `schools` table which contains school list, i have `subjects` table which contains subject list. Each school can specialize in one subject only, so `schools.spec_subject` is FK reference to one of entries in `subjects` table, which is handled by SQLAchemy via `School.spec_subject` property.

I want to allow users to add their own subjects and use them as school specialization.

I want to provide list of hardcoded subjects with an app, I want to be able to update it with future releases of the app, and I do not want to provide functionality to change these hardcoded subjects. So essentially, I want app code to provide hardcoded subjects and avoid storing them in database.

How can I achieve it? So far, the only way which came to mind is to have two columns for that: `schools.spec_subject_user` which has FK towards `subjects` table, and `schools.spec_subject_builtin` which just stores ID of built-in subjects. Then I just add custom getter which tries to access `spec_subject_user`, and if it is null - fetches built-in subject using value taken from `spec_subject_builtin`.

Are there saner ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be conflicting storing available values in a database and storing them in the app code.

Personally I would use the database: if other values are being stored in it, then it is a sensible place to store a basic list of valid values, and it will self maintain integrity.

However you could also use an enumerated type stored in app code:

```
import enum
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    maths = 'Mathematics'
    english = 'English'
    art = 'Fine Art'
```

Then define a column as

```
Column('value', Enum(MyEnum))
```

Your database column with then be populated with either: 'maths', 'english' 'art'

Comment: My app is downloadable, with user SQLite DB stored on user PC. In this case, if you wanted to prohibit user to edit built-in subjects, would you prohibit their modification via separate attribute, e.g. `editable`? And if you wanted to update them with new app release, would you do it via SQLAlchemy migration scripts?